# convertir fecha en jsgrid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

tengo una api que devuelve el campo fecha de la base de datos y la convierte de esta forma

`fecha = Convert.ToDateTime( row["fecha"].ToString())`

pero al mostrala en el jsGrid aparece de esta forma: /Date(1614232800000)/

En el jsGrid lo tengo de esta forma segun la documentación pero no me funciona:

```
        var MyDateField = function (config) {
        jsGrid.Field.call(this, config);
    };

    MyDateField.prototype = new jsGrid.Field({

        css: "date-field",           // redefine general property 'css'
        align: "center",             // redefine general property 'align'

        myCustomProperty: "itemTemplate",      // custom property
        itemTemplate: function (value) {
            if (value === null || value == undefined)
                return ""; var pattern = /Date(([^)]+))/; var results = pattern.exec(value);
            if (results != null) {
                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1])); return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
            }
            else { return ""; }
        }
    });

    jsGrid.fields.date = MyDateField;


$('#dgrecordsfound').jsGrid({
  width: "100%",
  height: "350px",
  filtering: false,
  inserting: false,
  editing: false,
  sorting: true,
  paging: true,
  autoload:true,
  pageButtonCount: 5,
  noDataContent:"No existen registros con estas especificiones.",
  loadIndication: true,
  loadMessage: "Cargando datos, espere por favor",

  pagercontainer:null,
  pageIndex: 1,
  pageSize: 6,
  pageButtonCount: 15,
  pagerFormat: "Páginas: {first} {prev} {pages} {next} {last} &nbsp;&nbsp; {pageIndex} de {pageCount}",
  pagePrevText: "Anterior",
  pageNextText: "Siguiente",
  pageFirstText: "Primera",
  pageLastText: "Última",
  pageNavigatorNextText: "...",
  pageNavigatorPrevText: "...",

  controller: {
     loadData: function () {
        return $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           datatype: "json",
           data: { parNombres: "@ViewBag.nombres"  , parApellidos: "@ViewBag.apellidos"},
           url: "/solicitudingresoasociado/getSolicitudIngresoByName"
        });
     },
  },

  fields: [
     {
        name: "cod_solicitud_ingreso",
        title: "Código",
        type: "text",
        width: 30
     },
     {
        name:"primer_nombre",
        title: "Nombre Solicitante",
        type: "text",
        width: 100
     },
     {
        name: "fecha",
        title: "Fecha",
         type: "date",
         width: 30
     },
     {
        name: "estado",
        title: "Estado",
        type: "text",
        width: 20
     }
  ],

  rowClick: function (itemselected) {
     var getdata = itemselected.item;
     var fields = Object.keys(getdata);
     var textarray = [];

     $.each(fields, function (idx, value) {
        textarray.push(getdata[value])
     });

     var url = '@Url.Action("indexllenobycode", "solicitud")' + '/id=1?parCodSolIngreso='+ textarray[1];
     window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Pero según la documentación no hay un type date como tal, sino que se puede convertir de otra forma, el caso es que no se como, ya que para efectos de la modificacion he realizado lo del codigo de arriba alguna idea bienvenida, gracias.

Pero según la documentación no hay un type date como tal, sino que se puede convertir de otra forma, el caso es que no se como, ya que para efectos de la modificacion he realizado lo del codigo de arriba alguna idea bienvenida, gracias.

[image: Campo Fecha]

Comment: Tendrias que obtener el indice del dato y de ahi pasarle una funcion que esa fecha te la convierta, mira este ejemplo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850708/proper-way-of-creating-date-fields-in-jsgrid

Comment: Fijate que eso ya lo intenté, en el link que me pasaste la respuesta que sugiere es la que te da en la documentación oficial del jsgrid, ya probe haciendolo así pero no me funciona.

Comment: Pudieras poner lo que intentas para ver a lo mejor algo estas poniendo mal

Comment: Ya coloqué el código tal cual lo tengo del jsgrid, segui los pasos según la documentación oficial pero de igual forma no me funciona, si le dejo el Date() así vacío me aparece en la vista la fecha actual, y si trato de llamar al field date del jsgrid me aparece invalid Date

Comment: Pero en function tienes que hacer que reciba el dato, ahi no le estas pasando nada fijate 
itemTemplate: function (value) {
        return new Date(value).toDateString();
    },

Comment: Ya lo modifiqué, y modifique el codigo de arriba para que veas como quedo ahora, y me aparece en el campo de la fecha como Invalid Date. Añadí una imagen de cómo se muestra.

Comment: Create esta funcion y la llamas para renderear la fecha
 this.RenderDate = function RenderDate(value) {
        if (value === null || value==undefined) return "";
        var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var results = pattern.exec(value);
        if (results != null) {
            var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
            return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

Comment: Esa función la coloco dentro del itemTemplate, o debajo del jsGrid.fields.date ? Disculpa mi ignorancia

Comment: Te creas una funcion en cualquier parte y lo mandas a llamar o si quieres saca el codigo y lo pegas ahi mismo, el chiste era para volver una funcion

Comment: Probando el código que me diste me devuelve en el campo de fecha así NaN/NaN/NaN en ese caso que podría modificar para que se muestre? De no mostrarme nada a esto es un gran paso

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y anexas el codigo a ver como lo dejaste

Comment: Ya modifiqué la pregunta y lo que modifiqué fue en el area de itemTemplate, le coloqué el código que me diste y en la pagina aparece como en la imagen, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: no entendi ya quedo?

Comment: Fijate que no, en el campo de la fecha ahora se muestra así NaN/NaN/NaN usando el código que me diste, subí una imagen de como se ve y el código cómo quedó ahora.

Comment: Hola, perdón me ocupe ayer :( y cual fue la resolución del problema?

Comment: Fijate que importando la libreria moment.js luego de leer la documentación logre darle formato a la fecha que me devolvian de la base de datos, ahora ya se muestra bien, gracias por tu tiempo, haces de este mundo un lugar mejor.